# How can I batch convert timezone of DATETIME entries?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For the past year and a half or so, our database server has been using Eastern Time, and the DATETIME type is used almost exclusively so datetimes in our databases have been timezone independent, since just the timestamp is stored. I've added some code in the application to be able to convert times to the local time zone in anticipation of changing this.

I know the best practice is to always use UTC, and I'd like to "cutover" to that now. I'm wondering what an easy way is of changing all the DATETIMEs in all the databases from Eastern time to UTC. By this, I mean literally modifying any DATETIME attributes for every single record, since changing the time zone on the server won't adjust those. Is there a command to easily do this?

I've been looking through some examples using CONVERT but these seem to just do that on the fly - not actually modify the data in the database. I'm sort of looking for something like:

`UPDATE [all tables] SET [all DATETIME attributes] = [current server/DB time (Eastern Time) -> UTC]`

(And then, hopefully, I could change the server time to UTC and nobody would notice anything had happened.)

But, to make matters worse, Daylight Savings has elapsed a few times in the past year and a half, so the simple approach of adding 5 hours to every datetime won't work, either. Is there an easy way out of this mess? Would `CONVERT_TZ` be sufficient or could that still muck things up?

Comment: Use the `CONVERT_TZ()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the process isn't necessarily complicated but it's not as obvious as one might hope, so I'm posting an answer. This is what worked for me:

1. Check if `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Eastern','US/Central');` does anything

First, make sure the above command doesn't return **NULL** when you execute it. If it does return **NULL**, as it did for me, complete steps 1 through 4 below:

1. cd to `/usr/bin`
2. `./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | ./mysql -u root -p --database=mysql`
3. Enter password
4. Run `service mariadb restart` (or appropriate command) to restart the DB service.
5. Run `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),'US/Eastern','US/Central');` - *now* it should now work! (not return **NULL**)
6. Run `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Etc/UTC`

Now run `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Etc/UTC';`

Now, the server time and the DB time are UTC.

Now, we must manually update all the appropriate columns to the UTC in the database.

For every applicable table and column combo, run something like this:

```
 UPDATE table SET `datetime` = CONVERT_TZ(`datetime`, 'America/New_York','Etc/UTC');
```

Now, the database time has been updated and all records are also updated to UTC.

Only caveat is you might want to watch for records that get added while you're updating the tables. Ideally, you'd prepare all this as a batch SQL statement, and execute it immediately after changing the server time so nothing slips by.

At the end, finally, run `service apache2 restart` to restart the web server. The DB in this case sits on the web server, and for some reason the times did not adjust properly until Apache was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Think through the full problem.

When you store a time of "08:00" into a `DATETIME`.  Everyone everywhere in the world will `SELECT` that "08:00".

When you store a time of "08:00" into a `TIMESTAMP`...

1. It is converted according to the timezone where you are `INSERTing` to UTC.
2. Someone doing `SELECT` will reconvert according to the timezone of the reader.  So he may not see "08:00".

Each of these actions is "correct" for some applications, but not for others.

There are about 5 patterns; MySQL/MariaDB provide only those two.

You can, with clumsy code, keep track of timezones separately and adjust where needed.  But, first, see whether proper configuration and use of `TIMESTAMP` would be simpler.

Note, also, that `DATETIME` screws up twice a year (if your area used "Daylight Savings Time") -- an extra hour once a year, and a missing hour.

Comment: TIMESTAMP auto updates without jumping through hoops, so I've avoided that for everything. Also, how does DATETIME mess up if you are using UTC, as we are now after the switch?

Comment: @InterLinked -- Oops, "if you use DST"

Comment: That's the whole point. We were using DATETIME in Eastern time which was bound to create issues. That's why I spearheaded this migration to UTC - so that would become a nonissue

Comment: Eastern has DST issues.  If you switch to TIMESTAMP, perhaps all the problems vanish.

Comment: I'm not sure the point is getting across. We were able to successfully move to UTC. No database times are in Eastern anymore. The time zone conversions is completely handled by PHP where necessary